# How to update the data in an array with a specific array key?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a cart using session and 2D array my problem is i want to change the content of one of the array in 2D array and i have an order id just to make sure that it changes the correct array, here's my code please help me;

This is the code for inserting new item:

```
if(isset($_POST['addtocart'])){
    $count= count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $newproduct= array(
        'id' =>  $count,
        'code' => $_SESSION['code'],
        'color' => $_POST['color'],
        'type' => $_POST['type'],
        'size' =>$_POST['size'],
        'quantity' => 1
    );
    $_SESSION['cart'][]= $newproduct;
}
```

`$_SESSION['cart']` is the name of my 2D array. Now here's the sample list:

```
$_SESSION['cart']=> array([0] =>(array
order=> 0,  
code=> 123,  
color=> blue,  
type=> us,  
size=> M.  
quantity => 1 );
([1] =>(array
order=> 1,  
code=> 125,  
color=> red,  
type=> uk,  
size=> S.  
quantity => 1 );
```

Now I want to update the quantity of a the array with an id of 125, but supposed I don't know the id. In my cart list I have a selectbox that automatically submits when an option is selected. Here's my code;

```
    <select name="quantity1" id="quantity" onchange="javascript: submit()" >
<option value="<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>"><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></option>
<?php
    $sql2 = "SELECT * from color_variation 
    WHERE  color='$color' 
    AND size='$size' 
    AND size_type='$type'";
    $q2= $conn->query($sql2);
    $q2->setFetchMode (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($r2 = $q2->fetch())
    {
        $x= $r2['quantity'];
    }
    for($y=1; $y<=$x; $y++){
        if($y== $r1['quantity']){

        } else{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $y; ?>"><?php echo $y; ?></option>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

when it submits heres my code for updating the array for a specific array key:

```
if(isset($_POST['quantity1'])){
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity1']; 

    $cart= $_SESSION['cart'];
    foreach($cart as  &$value)
    {
        $value['quantity']= $quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is to separate your SQL (SELECT * FROM.....) from this file and put it somewhere else. The you can include it or elsehow use it in this file.

Comment: the sql query is used to populate the option in a select box and the numbers in it will be the quantity and it is based on the quantity of the product in my database

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do. Do you really mean the id 125? I noticed you have a code key in your array which is 125 in one of them, is that the one you mean?

As suggested above you should also structure your code better, now it's hardly readable.

Comment: i did it that way because what if he orders 5 pcs of that ithem and there are only 3 stocks .?

Comment: yeah, but not just 125 what if i will change the quantity of the array having id of 123 not the 125. cases like that .